# Does Selenium IDE 1.10.0 support Firefox 19.0.2

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to create a sample python script using Selenium IDE 1.10.0 with Firefox version 19.0.2.

I am able to create the script, but during run time i'm getting exception: "INFO - Got result: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser on session null"

So my question is that can i run the generated script against Firefox version 19.0.2. If yes then why i'm getting this error, if not then please provide me your input.

Thanks in Advance
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE 1.10.0 release notes says it only supports upto Firefox 17 so you may face issue with v19. will you re-try downgrading Firefox please?

Comment: Yes, Selenium IDE 1.10.0 support Firefox 19.0.2.  Just we have to download the updated RC server (selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0). After running this server user can execute the created Script.